# Use reflection to get value of inherited static property that changed on cctor of child class

Tags: c#, system.reflection

```cs
public abstract class a
{
    public static string Description { get; protected set; }
}

public class b : a
{
    static b()
    {
        Description = "asdf";
    }
}
```

I want to access b.description with reflection (and its value would be "asdf") but find any good solution.

Comment: In this context you know about type `a`, why can't you just say `a.Description`?

Comment: I edited my post I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection, you have to specify ALL the flags you want.

Here is the sample.

```
private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    b obj = new b();
    var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public );
    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty( "Description", 
        BindingFlags.Static |
        BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |
        BindingFlags.Public
        );
    MessageBox.Show( prop.GetValue( obj, null ).ToString() );
}
```

However if you elaborate on your use case, there may be better solution than reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
        // Get a PropertyInfo of specific property type(T).GetProperty(....)
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
    propertyInfo = typeof(b)
        .GetProperty("Description", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

    // Use the PropertyInfo to retrieve the value from the type by not passing in an instance
    object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(new b(), null);
```

value is description value:

```
asdf
```

For more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_MethodBase_Invoke_System_Object_System_Object___